# How to set unique constraint in Quill.io with case class

Tags: scala, quill.io

I am using quill library and mapping entities via case classes
`case class Country(id: Long, name: String)`

How can I set unique
 constraint on **name** field?

Comment: As far as I know there is no such feature in Qull. Only Slick library has

Comment: You have to make constraint in your database - quill only creates queries.